# How to find which all check box is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of check box and i need to write a javascript function to find out which all the check boxes are clicked. can any one help?

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" id="name" /> name
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" id="age" /> age
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" id="school" /> school
   <input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" id="company"> company
```

So if I click on only 2 I need to know which are the 2 I clicked on so that I can send for server side processing.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the checkboxes all have the same name, you can use a function like:

```
function getChecked(name) {
  var els = document.getElementsByName(name);

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    if (els[i].checked) {
      // els[i] is checked, do stuff
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a input type button and call this function on it's click

```
function callMeOnButtonClick()
{

  var selectedBox  = document.querySelectorAll('input[name*=check_group]');
  // You may also use
  // var selectedBox = document.getElementsByName('check_group[]');
  // The above two statements will give you the same result. i.e., array of checkboxes having name check_group[]

  var count++;
  for(var i=0; i<selectedBox.length; i++)
  {
      if(selectedBox[i].checked)
      {
          count++;
          // Do processing
      }
  }
  alert("Number of selected checkbox: "+count);
}
```

Comment: All the checkboxes have the same name, so `getElementsByName` seems more appropriate and is more widely supported.

Comment: Yeah right!! correct my code to count the checked checkboxes :) @PeeHaa Thanks

Answer (score -2):

you can use jQuery to find the checked elements in javascript

```
alert($("check_group[]:[checked=checked]").length);
```

and then you can use those values to send server side for processing

Comment: He ask for javascript and not jQuery